# Element not hidden when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Why `display = "none"` not works when button is clicked in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pUeue/3441/)?

**HTML:**

```
<div>This is a visible heading<div>
<div class="hidden">This is a hidden heading</div>
<div>Notice that the hidden heading still takes up space.</div>

<hr/>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('input[type=button]').click( function() {
 document.getElementsByClassName("hidden").style.display = "none";
});
```

Comment: Lol, why mix jQuery an vanilla JS?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pUeue/3446/

Comment: @nicael because they are both libraries :)))

Comment: @madalin What do you mean by "both"?.. JS is not a library of JS.

Comment: @madalinivascu `javascript` is not a `library` ...

Comment: it was a joke lol so worked-up :))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName()` returns [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which is an Array like object. You are trying to apply HTML Node properties on this array.

First select DOM Node from this array then apply style properties as shown below.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("hidden")[0].style.display = "none";
```

```js
$('input[type=button]').click( function() {
 document.getElementsByClassName("hidden")[0].style.display = "none";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>This is a visible heading<div>
<div class="hidden">This is a hidden heading</div>
<div>Notice that the hidden heading still takes up space.</div>

<hr/>

<input type="button" value="test" />
```

Alternatively you can use jQuery to hide element.

```js
$('input[type=button]').click(function() {
  $(".hidden").first().hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>This is a visible heading<div>
  <div class="hidden">This is a hidden heading</div>
  <div>Notice that the hidden heading still takes up space.</div>

  <hr/>

  <input type="button" value="test" />
```

In Pure JavaScript you can do it as follows:

```js
var button = document.getElementsByClassName('button')[0];

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
 document.getElementsByClassName("hidden")[0].style.display = "none";
}, false);
```

```html
<div>This is a visible heading<div>
<div class="hidden">This is a hidden heading</div>
<div>Notice that the hidden heading still takes up space.</div>

<hr/>

<input class="button" type="button" value="test" />
```

Comment: Nice answer, can you include a pure JS method too? Then I can remove my answer as this is something really simple to do in pure JS.

Comment: why not use `first()`?

Comment: @madalinivascu Thanks a lot, I've updated my answer)

Comment: @Albzi I've added a pure JavaScript solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could use jQuery to do it easily, you already had included it to your project, so it is no overhead. Simply use `hide()` to remove the element from view:

```
$('input[type=button]').click(function() {
    $(".hidden").hide();
});
```

**[Working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/pUeue/3443/)**

Answer (score 1):

The `document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array of classes.

chose the first element of the array.

```js
$('input[type=button]').click( function() {
 document.getElementsByClassName("hidden")[0].style.display = "none";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>This is a visible heading<div>
<div class="hidden">This is a hidden heading</div>
<div>Notice that the hidden heading still takes up space.</div>

<hr/>

<input type="button" id="test" value="test" />
```

Here is the updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pUeue/3445/)

Answer (score 1):

No need to mix jQuery and JavaScript, here is a JS method:

```
document.querySelector('input').onclick = function() {
  document.querySelector('.hidden').style.display = "none";
}
```

The reason your `getElementsByClassName` wont work is because it's an array. You either need to loop through it and `display:hide;` all of them, or get a specific one by appending `[n]` after it (`n` being the number of the element you want in the array, starting at `0`).

```js
document.querySelector('input').onclick = function() {
  document.querySelector('.hidden').style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div>This is a visible heading<div>
<div class="hidden">This is a hidden heading</div>
<div>Notice that the hidden heading still takes up space.</div>

<hr/>

<input type="button" value="test" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Why using Native JS when you have jQuery used on page.

http://jsfiddle.net/ritesh14887/pUeue/3442/

```
$('input[type=button]').click( function() {
 $(".hidden").css('display','none');
});
```